# как правильно отсортировать массив объектов?

Tags: javascript

```js
const foo = [9, 2, 3, 'random', 'panda'];
// returns [ 2, 3, 9, 'panda', 'random' ]

const bar = [4, 19, 30, function() {}, {
  key: 'value'
}];
// returns [ 19, 30, 4, { key: 'value' }, [Function] ]





const bands = [ 
  { genre: 'Rap', band: 'Migos', albums: 2},
  { genre: 'Pop', band: 'Coldplay', albums: 4},
  { genre: 'Rock', band: 'Breaking Benjamins', albums: 1}
];

/* returns [ 
{ genre: 'Pop', band: 'Coldplay', albums: 4 }, 
{ genre: 'Rap', band: 'Migos', albums: 2 }, 
{ genre: 'Rock', band: 'Breaking Benjamins', albums: 1 } 
] */
```

Comment: отсортировать по каким правилам?

Comment: @Grundy по правилам, встроенных в язык функций для сортировки. или лучше свою написать ?